# Generate dictionary with AutoFixture

Tags: c#, dictionary, autofixture

For a list, we can do

```
fixture.CreateMany<List<string>>(1000); // with 1000 elements
```

but how to do it with a dictionary? And to be able to specify the number of elements to be generated.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You could simply create the items then build the dictionary, like this:

```
fixture
  .CreateMany<KeyValuePair<int, string>>(1000)
  .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
```

This is more-or-less what AutoFixture [does internally](https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture/blob/master/Src/AutoFixture/DictionaryFiller.cs#L57-L63).

Another alternative would be to create a new `ICustomization`, which intercepts requests for any `Dictionary<,>` and builds them. It could be implemented using code from [existing](https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture/blob/master/Src/AutoFixture/MultipleCustomization.cs#L53-L58) [classes](https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture/blob/master/Src/AutoFixture/DictionaryFiller.cs#L57-L63).